# Seaborn Error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xda' in position 4710: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, data-analysis

I'm trying to create a bar graph similar to this example https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_barplot.html

My code is as follows:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
df_noshow = sns.load_dataset(df)

g = sns.catplot(x="Noshow", y="SMS_received", hue="Gender", 
data=df_noshow, height=6, kind="bar", palette="muted")
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("Text Message Received")
```

I'm getting this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xda' in position 4710: ordinal not in range(128)

Additionally, I'm not 100% sure I did the following code correctly:

```
df_noshow = sns.load_dataset(df)
```

I did create df earlier with
    import pandas as pd
    df= pd.read_csv('noshow2016.csv')

and all the previous code has been working and I can't imagine the unicode error having anything to do with csv file not loading correctly, however I wanted to include it just in case. Thank you.

Comment: ASCII contains code points < 128 only. 0xDA > 128, hence can't be encoded in ASCII

Comment: A stack trace might help identify the function where ASCII is assumed. Then documentation might help follow its rules.